# How to implement webrtc for sdpOffer to kurento with c#?

Tags: c#, webrtc, kurento

I implement webrtc with c#.Have any tutorial or sample to gen sdpOffer to kurento.
I think Iwill sent sdp by websocket to kurento. But I don't know format sdp to sent request  for get pipeline_id from kurento.

Thankyou for advance

Answer (score 0):

KMS exposes a websocket port for signaling: creating, destroying, connecting, configuring... media elements. The control protocol is called [Kurento Protocol](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mastering/kurento_protocol.html). Please read the documentation linked there to implement your own version of the KurentoClient.